# Providing CMYK support at JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf, cmyk

I have to generate report using Java and *iReport 5.6*.

I have created a pdf report and it is working fine. The problem is that /i have to send this pdf report for printing press for newsletter and the generated pdf is using RGB color. For printing material we usually use CMYK color scheme.

I want to ask is there any way to generate this pdf using CMYK? How to generate pdf report using iReport using CMYK color scheme? Is their any setting that will make CMYK default color scheme so when ever I export pdf it should take CMYK?

Is there any other tool by which I can fullfull my requirement?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: [Addition of CMYK Support in JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/519432/addition-cmyk-support-jasperreports)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply but i have already search alot and went through all jasper community posts but this is not complete solution i have to generate pdf from java using CMYK color scheme if any tool other than i report can do this please suggest that